# window.location isn't working with a server call function with signalR

Tags: javascript, signalr

That's my code:

```
<input type="button" id="SignOut" value="SignOut"  onclick="logout();" />
```

**ServerSide:**

```
public void ondisconnected() // when the user is disconnected
{
    try
    { 
        DataRow[] UserRow = ConnectedClientDt.Select("ConnectionID='" + Context.ConnectionId + "'");
        int ClientID = Convert.ToInt32(UserRow[0][0]);
        new SQLHelper(SQLHelper.ConnectionStrings.WebSiteConnectionString).Update("Update clients set USER_STATUS='F' where CLIENT_ID=" + ClientID);
        string query = " Select FRIEND_ID from friends where CLIENT_ID= " + ClientID;
        DataTable FriendsDt = new SQLHelper(SQLHelper.ConnectionStrings.WebSiteConnectionString).getQueryResult(query);
        for (int i = 0; i < FriendsDt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow[] FrRow = ConnectedClientDt.Select("ClientId=" + FriendsDt.Rows[i][0] + "");
            if (FrRow.Length > 0)
                Clients.Client(FrRow[0][2].ToString()).userDisconnected(ClientID);
        }
        DeleteUser(Context.ConnectionId);  
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ;
    }
}
```

**ClientSide:**

```
function logout() {
    $.connection.chatHub.server.ondisconnected();
    setTimeout(window.location= "LoginPage.aspx?action=logout", 5000);
}
```

When i press the button the ondisconnected function isn't excuting but when i remove settimeout line the code is working properly without any problem :s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This following bit of code will trigger the `window.location` the moment it is evaluated, which is not what you are wanting:

```
setTimeout(window.location= "LoginPage.aspx?action=logout", 5000);
```

You need:

```
setTimeout(function(){window.location="LoginPage.aspx?action=logout"}, 5000);
```

By wrapping the code in a function it will only be executed when the function is called, which will occur 5 seconds later. Your previous version would have evaluated the `window.location` immediately, meaning `signalr` would not have had time to communicate with the server.

Comment: @sora no problem :) good place to read about `setTimeout` is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout